# onchange event not working on Salesforce ios app and Safari browser

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, community, lightning-design-system

We have a Salesforce application developed with LWC and published on Experience site. We also launched this application in android and iphone. The application is working fine in Windows Desktop and Android phone but it is breaking on Safari browser and iPhone. The onchange and onblur events are not getting triggered on apple devices. Anyone has a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can just set a condition when page load in iphone and when page laod in other os.

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i))
{
      $(".no_phone").on("blur", function() {
         alert("changed");
      })
}
else{
      $(".no_phone").on("change", function() {
         alert("changed");
      })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The issue was related to Date variable and we resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not with the onChange event but with the Date parameter we were processing. Appraently iphone accepts date only in the format of dd/mm/yyyy. Since we had date parameter not matching to the iphone expectations our code wasn't executing. After we changed the value it started working fine.